# What are the cascading rules when additional className is passed as prop in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-props

I have a custom component in one file, lets say like that:

```
import styles from './CustomComponent.module.css'

export default CustomComponent = ({className, onClick, text, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.container} ${className}`}>{text}</div>
    )
}
```

That component is imported into another file, which has it's own components and css module:

```
import styles from './ParentComponent.module.css'
import CustomComponent from '../CustomComponent/CustomComponent.js'

export default ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            This is an example.
            <CustomComponent text='Example' className={styles.overrideStyle} />
        </>
    )
}
```

What I want to happen is that the overrideStyle can be used to add css parameters and/or override some existing ones of the container style. What happens is that new parameters are added, if were not previously defined in the container style, but already existing ones are not overwritten.

For example, if containerStyle is something like:

```
.containerStyle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and overrideStyle is something like this:

```
.overrideStyle {
    height: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
```

I expected the resulting css properties of the CustomComponent div to be as follows:

```
.(combined) {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

What I get is:

```
.(combined){
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

New properties are added, but existing ones are not overwritten.

This leads me to believe that the className that was passed as a prop is defined above the container in the CSS cascade, but I don't see a reason for that and moreover, I have not found a workaround.

What rules are there that I don't understand and how can I force the className that is passed through props to supersede the default one?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding your question somewhat confusing. It's just props and you need to handle them logically. I don't know if your className is a string or what, but maybe you're looking for something like

```
import styles from './CustomComponent.module.css'

export default CustomComponent = ({className, onClick, text, ...props}) => {
    className = className ? className : styles.container

    return (
        <div className={className}>{text}</div>
    )
}
```

You could also use default props.

Comment: I modified my answer so that it hopefully is more clear. My goal is not to completely replace the existing properties, but add or override some of them.